# comparing a input string to string in a database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm studying Android studio and started with databases this week. I would like a little help with this app. It is simple. The user enters a string and presses a button in the first activity. This string then is sent to the second activity where it is compared with values in a database and display the ones that are similar:

```
public class DrinkCategoryActivity extends ListActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;
private Cursor newcursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String messageText = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_category);
    ListView listDrinks = getListView();
    try{
        SQLiteOpenHelper starbucksDatabaseHelper = new StarbucksDatabaseHelper(this);
        db = starbucksDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        /*
            SELECT _id, NAME FROM DRINKS;
         */
        cursor = db.query("DRINK",
                    new String[]{"_id", "NAME"},
                    null, null, null, null, null);
        newcursor = cursor.equals(messageText);
        CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"NAME"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0);

        listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }catch (SQLiteException ex){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database unavailable",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
```

i have been looking all over the web but i can not find a good explanation.
database

this is the database were are the drinks

```
public class StarbucksDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    add a varaible for the db name
    private static final String DB_NAME = "starbucks";

    version of the database
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    StarbucksDatabaseHelper (Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DRINK ("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "NAME TEXT, "
                + "DESCRIPTION TEXT, "
                + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER);");
     insert data
        insertDrink(db, "Soy Latte", "Esspresso and steamed soy milk", R.drawable.latte);
        insertDrink(db, "Mocaccino", "Esspresso, hot milk, steamed milk foam, and cocoa", R.drawable.cappuccino);
        insertDrink(db, "American", "Drip coffee", R.drawable.filter);
    }

    private static void insertDrink (SQLiteDatabase db,
                                     String name,
                                     String description,
                                     int resourceId){
        ContentValues drinkValues = new ContentValues();
        drinkValues.put("NAME", name );
        drinkValues.put("DESCRIPTION", description);
        drinkValues.put("IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID", resourceId);


        db.insert("DRINK", null, drinkValues);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
```

Comment: Why you added newcursor = cursor.equals(messageText);? also, the answer to your question depends upon how do you want  to match the string with your database - exactly same or contains that string, starts with it, ends with it ,.....?

Comment: I forgot to remove that . i will like  if it could check world by world because the strings in the databases  could have more that two world and the and i will like that it displayed all the string that are similar to the string that the user enters

Comment: Can you explain by giving an example ?

Comment: if the user input student and in the databases there it is                         student id,                                                                                           student  services                                                                                                   room                                                                                                          i will like to display the two that have student

Answer (score 1):

Try this query instead if you want that any row containing your `messageText` in the start, middle or the end should be retrieved -

```
cursor = db.query("DRINK", new String[]{"_id", "NAME"}, "NAME like %?%", new String[]{messageText}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Then I guess there is no value matching with your database records.

Comment: my input was the same that one of the values in the databases

Comment: Can you attach your database screenshot and what is the value of "messagetext" you are passing to the query.

Comment: i posted the databases

Comment: I meant database records . use the plugin I mentioned and verify.

Comment: Also, what is the "messagetext" you are passing ?

Comment: the messagetext is a edittext view in the first activity that it a string then is passed to the second activity

Comment: Try this - ursor = db.query("DRINK", new String[]{"_id", "NAME"}, "NAME like '%"+ messageText + "%'", null, null, null, null);

Comment: it keeps to display the toast

Comment: seriously this is really complicade

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using the `trim()` attached to the strings you are checking. What's happening is most likely, the one in the database is stored with an extra character.